# How do I start Polarion xwiki velocity script development?

Tags: velocity, polarion

How do I start Polarion xwiki velocity script development? I am new to velocity scripts and Polarion.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Apache Velocity Engine documentation to learn about Velocity syntax: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html

Also, Polarion adds some custom object that can be used to interact with its API, you can see what is available by editing a wiki page, click the "Detailed Syntax Help" link on the right panel, and in the page that opens check the Polarion SDK section.

It is also useful to check the wiki pages in the demo projects to get a feel of how they works.